# From "Add To Cart" to "Added To Cart"

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

How to change from "Add To Cart" to "Added To Cart" in react.js on clicking the "Add To Cart" button?
Here is my "Add To Cart" button.

```
<button
className="btn"
onClick={() =>
    addProductToCart(products)
    }
>
Add to cart
</button>
```

Here is the addProductToCart handler

```
const addProductToCart = (product) => {
            const newProduct = {
                ...product,
                count: 1,
            };
            setProducts([
                ...productsInCart,
                newProduct,
            ]);
        };
```

Can I achieve this using useState?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct if you have one Product in that page. From your comments, I can see that each product has Add to cart button. In this case your product object should have a property 'isAddedToCart'. You need to use map function to display button for each products as well

Here is the sample code

```
  const addProductToCart = (product) => {
            const newProduct = {
                ...product,
                count: 1,
                isAddedToCart: true
            };
            
            setProducts(products.map(p => (p.id === newProduct.id 
   ? newProduct : p)))};
        return ({
    products.map(p => (
<button
    className="btn"
    key={p.id}
    onClick={() =>
        addProductToCart(p)
        }
    >
    {p.isAddedToCart ? 'Added to Cart' : 'Add to Cart'}
    </button>
))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can we use isAddedToCart outside of the addProductToCart function? It will give an error.